# EF4, self tracking, repository pattern, SQL Server 2008 AND SQL Server Compact

Tags: entity-framework, repository, c#-4.0, self-tracking-entities

I am creating a project using Entity Frameworks 4 and self tracking entities.  I want to be able to either get the data from a sql server 2008 database or from sql server compact database (with the switch being in the config file).  I am using the repository pattern and I will have the self tracking entities sitting in a separate assembly.

Do I need two edmx files?  If so, how do I generate only one set of STE's in the separate assembly?  Also do I need to generate two context classes as well?  I am unsure of the plumbing for all this.  Can anyone help?

Darren

I forgot to add that the two databases will be identical and that the compact version is for offline usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to follow up on this.  In the end I had to maintain two separate edmx files, one for sql server and one for compact.  The main reason being that compact 3.5 does not support auto identities (as mentioned above by Zeeshan).  This in turn led to two context classes. In the context class for sql server compact I had to put code to check for insertions, query the database for the latest id and increment it manually before saving.

Thankfully with the release of compact 4.0 this no longer applies as it supports auto id and you can indeed use just one edmx file.

Darren

Answer (score 0):

You do need the edmx file as long as the schema is exactly the same. just change the connectionstring and everything would work seamlessly. Though i am not sure how u are saying that schema is same when compact edition does not support identity concept and full blown sql server does. So if you are using features specific to sql server that's not available in compact, then you would get runtime errors.